# Tmux command to run shell command on active pane?

Tags: tmux

I understand that `run-shell` command runs the code in a "global" session which isn't necessarily linked to any active window, pane or session. However I would like to bind a key to run a command in the shell for the active pane.

Use case: map a key to opening `vim` in the current active pane (perhaps with certain parameters). Just like you would run `run-shell "command command-parameters*"`.

Is there a way to do this in tmux?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Sending commands to the current pane

If you run `tmux send-keys vim Enter`, that will send the literal keypresses to your current pane to spawn vim. You can then bind this to whatever key combination you like.

Caveat: Because this is sending literal key presses, not directly executing a specified path, the pane needs a shell (e.g. bash/zsh/fish) already running inside to interpret what is being sent.

### Targeting a specific pane by index

In tmux, sessions have alphanumeric names, and windows & panes have both unique IDs and 0-indexed positions (see also TMUX_PANE below). Some commands allow you to target specific panes with the `-t` flag by specifying those names/indexes/IDs as a parameter.

The syntax of a target is quite flexible (see the COMMANDS section of the manpage, for target-session and target-window), and this is just one example:

`session-name:window-index.pane-index`

For example, to open vim in the current session, sixth window, second pane:

`tmux send-keys -t ":5.1" vim Enter`

When an id in the target is empty/unspecified (as the session name is in the above example), the currently active session/window/pane is used. The `5` specifies the sixth window, counting up from 0. The `1` specifies the second pane of the sixth window - again, counting up from 0.

### $TMUX_PANE

Each window & pane in tmux has a uniquely identifying ID, distinct across all of the server's active sessions. This is separate to its index, which may change when windows/panes are re-ordered or re-arranged.

A pane's ID is exposed via the `$TMUX_PANE` environment variable, and in tmux it is usable in a format string via `#{pane_id}` or the shortcut `#D`:

```
% echo "TMUX_PANE: $TMUX_PANE"
TMUX_PANE: %35
% tmux display-message -p 'pane_id: #{pane_id} (#D)'
pane_id: %35 (%35)
```

The unique pane ID can also be used as a target for various tmux commands, e.g. `tmux rename-window -t $TMUX_PANE $new_name`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the thorough explanation! :D