How to write a script that finds an already open terminal and then executes a command in that terminal
I work on multiple terminal for my task, now i have to manually run refresh commands everyday i start working, I want to create a cron job that runs a script that finds my open terminal and run few commands for me
I tried using script that run spawns a terminal and runs the command but that is solving my problem as i have to open a new terminal and again run some commands

You didn't tell us what kind of terminal you are running. Basically, you need a terminal emulator which can accept somehow from the outside a string and use this as a command.  Should be technically possible, but I don't know whether someone has implemented such a terminal program. You also did not say what Window manager you are using, but if it is based on X, xdotool could be used to send keystrokes to a certain window.

If you use a terminal multiplexer like tmux you can do this; see e.g. the scripting tmux documentation.

@user1934428 i am using a basic csh konsole. Kde is the window manager

csh is a shell, not a terminal.

cron job that runs a script that finds my open terminal why do you need a terminal? Why not just run the command without terminal?

@KamilCuk i usually require to open terminal and run some commands that setups a kind of virtual env which takes at 20-30 mins, now i thought that if could automate this then i can save 30 mins of my life everyday

Yes, i agree, you require a terminal, as stated. How about, don't require a terminal? Just execute commands from cron, without a terminal. why do you need a terminal? What purpouse does a terminal serve? You seem to want to execyte command periodically - so i suggest to execute them from cron. If you want log file, you can redirect the logs of commands to a file or system log.

@KamilCuk the thing is we need a terminal to access the codebase. So we create a sort of virtual env in the terminal and access the code make the code, now as many people merge the code at their own time, if i need to merge something i need to be on the latest codeline hence the refresh. Now what you said regarding having a cron job run without the terminal yes that will work and refresh the code line but then my virtual env open in the terminal will not be in a sync and i will have to exit and enter it again which will take 30 mins. (We are not using git, it is a pain i know )

Why do you need a terminal to access the codebase? I do not understand. So what are you using? You can't create "sort of virtual env" without a terminal? what exactly do you create, using what commands, what environmnet, what is "virtual env" exactly? Do you create a QEMU virtual machine? Do you install some pip packages and update PYTHONPATH? Could you be more specific? We are not using git, it is a pain i know Great, so what are you using exactly? Some in house solution? SVN, mercurial? Why do you need a terminal?

but then my virtual env open in the terminal will not be in a sync and i will have to exit and enter it again What exactly is "virtual env" then? What does it mean exactly to "be in a sync"? What do you have to "exit and enter" exactly again? So many questions! If you want to update some environment variables in a currently running program, that is not possible - linux comes with process isolation, secutiry, as in one process cannot affect the other that easily. TMUX or other terminal multiplexer, where you can send text via command line to that terminal, sounds like a solution for you.

Also, very kindly, if my comments are not to your liking or I'm asking too many intricate questions, feel free to tell me, I'll go and delete them.

@KamilCuk sorry it seems i have not been specific on my part. We use ADE as our version control and in ade we need to create a view( which gets the code and sets some required env variable) then we have to enter that view (takes around 30 mins for me) and then we can work. Now the view we create is created on a label (latest code) and a new label get created everyday so we need to refresh our views once a day and that too takes time. So i just wanted to refresh my views with a script.

Now if we do refresh is through a cron job then my view open in my terminal might get out of sync as i mentioned previously.

Hi. What you described in your comment should have been your post. Consider asking a new question, where you specifically ask how to refresh ade view in a batch script from cron. Consider writing specifically what ade commands you execute interactively from your terminal every day and the results and outputs you are getting and expecting to get. You might be interested in https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Finding an open terminal and executing commands within in very very much depends on the terminal you are using. As such, if you are using konsole consider adding it to this question. If you are interested in any terminal, then there are many many helps for tmux, like i just googled https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/409861/is-it-possible-to-send-input-to-a-tmux-session-without-connecting-to-it , https://superuser.com/questions/492266/run-or-send-a-command-to-a-tmux-pane-in-a-running-tmux-session https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48292906/tmux-command-to-run-shell-command-on-active-pane

IMO it's easier to poll from all terminals than push from one terminal to all.

In appropriate rc file (e.g. .bashrc, .bash_profile, .profile) just start a simple loop that runs once a day. E.g.

while true; do
  sleep 86400  # 24 hours
  # ... refresh commands ...
done &


If you want something more on demand, instead of on a fixed schedule

while true; do
  sleep 60
  if -r /tmp/commands-to-execute.sh; then
    echo "running /tmp/commands-to-execute.sh"
    bash /tmp/commands-to-execute.sh
  fi
done &

Now you can run following whenever you want to run some refresh commands in all your open terminals:
cat << EO_REFRESH_CMDS > /tmp/commands-to-execute.sh
# ... refresh commands ...
EO_REFRESH_CMDS

sleep 50
rm /tmp/commands-to-execute.sh

If you don't wanna rely on sleep 50 then you can create a /tmp/$$.executed after executing commands and check for it's existence to ensure you don't execute if it's already executed, and delete /tmp/$$.executed if it's older than say an hour or two.

thanks a lot, this will help a lot. I can also add a check to see if the env requires a refresh.
